# Where do the arguments of a function get passed in

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, express, callback

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
   console.log(req)
});
```

Where do the actual arguments to this function get passed in when the function is called, and what is providing the arguments to the function.

Meaning my understanding of a function is, first you have the function definition

```
function timesTwo(x){
   return 2*x
}
```

Where x is a parameter. This block of code alone will not execute any function as it hasn't been called and provided an argument

```
timesTwo(3) //will return 6
```

Only works because I have called the function and passed an argument of 3

So why does

```
function(req, res, next) {
   console.log(req)
});
```

work if I haven't called / provided an argument like in the timesTwo function

Comment: You are passing a function to `app.use`, and it will be called from there, In Javascript you can pass functions and variables around.

Comment: This is called `callback` function. You don't call it. You pass it to another function which does something and when results are ready it calls your `callback` function with parameters.

Comment: But where does req,res come from aren't those just Placeholder parameter like 'x' in my example.

Comment: `app.use` provides req, res and next.

Comment: They are coming from when the application calls your function.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a callback function that will be called later.

Here is an example:

```js
const app = {
  list:[],
  use(fn) {
    // save  the reference to the function so it can be called later
    this.list.push(fn);
  },
  handle() {
    // The callback function is called here. Notice that I don't know what
    // the function was called, and it doesn't matter if it was a named
    // or anonymous function. I just call it with whatever arguments
    // I want.
    const time = new Date().toISOString();
    this.list.forEach( fn => fn( time ) );
  }
}

setInterval(app.handle.bind(app), 2000);

function myFunction (time) {
  console.log('MYFUNC', time)
};

app.use(myFunction); // Adds a named function
app.use( function(time) { console.log("Anonymous", time) } ); // adds an anonymous function
```

Answer (score -1):

This is not a user-defined function this is actually middleware(you can say callback function as well) in the express framework. The arguments have already set/manage by the express framework. It will execute automatically when you request sent to the server.

Comment: `This is not a user-defined function` This is a user defined function